# How to call a different function after completion of one function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have written long code, trying to replicate the situation in simple form by this simple code.

What I want to do is after `function A()` completion, call `function B()`.
I am trying with `callback` function but in this case, `B` fired early.
Please suggest how can I write this `callback` or any other approach?

```
function A(callback){

    a()
    function a() {
        setTimeout(aa,1000)
        function aa(){
            console.log("in aa")
        }           
    }

    b()
    function b() {
        setTimeout(bb,100)
        function bb(){
            console.log("in bb")
        }       
    }
    c()
    function c(){
        setTimeout(cc,50)
        function cc(){
            console.log("in cc")
        }       
    }
    callback();

}

function B() {
    console.log("in B");
}

A(B)

output
in B
in cc
in bb
in aa
```

Comment: Either use `promises`, either call the next function in the previous function's timeout. More about promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: using a setTimeout means that your code will be executed later once the call stack is cleared...no matter how.much milliseconds you set....it will get executed later...so your callback() is immediately put into the call stack and get called

Answer (score 1):

If you want your callback to run after a timeout has finished, then you have to call it when the timeout has **finished**.

And that means it needs to be at the end of the function you pass to `setTimeout`.

With your current code, you are setting the countdown on the timeout going and then **immediately** calling the callback.

```js
function one(callback) {
  console.log(1);

  function two() {
    console.log(2);
    callback();
  }
  setTimeout(two, 250);
}

function three() {
  console.log(3);
}

one(three);
```

Comment: Till now I set, setTimeout of 5sec and it is working fine, but the thing is (which I am not sure) if the server will become busy then this program will collapse, that is why looking for proper solution in terms of callback etc

Comment: @ErDeepakGarg — The specific amount of time the timeout is set for doesn't matter.

Comment: "Is there server will become busy"? There is no server involved in your question. It is plain client-side JS. It sounds like you have an XY Question and asked the wrong question here.

Comment: The main project is 1000 lines of code.... so I tried to express in short where I stucked. In this question, I just want to know how to run B() after completion of A() completely.

Comment: @ErDeepakGarg — There is no magic way to detect when every asynchronous function initiated by A has finished. You need to write code to deal with it explicitly. (Designing the asynchronous functions to use Promises and combining them using Promise.all can make that easier).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what's happening  here (as you requested) is that you want B to run after A is completed.

There is no need to use "B" as a callback, with async/await.

B will wait till A is completed before it's called.

```js
const b = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve("B done")}, 1000);
  });
}
const c = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve("C done")}, 500);
  });
}

const A = async () => {
  const bres = await b();
  console.log(bres);
  const cres = await c();
  console.log(cres);
};

const B = async () => {
  console.log("done");
}

const app = async() => {
  await A();
  await B();
};

app();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you did, you changed the whole question I guess. I want when A() function ends then B() runs?

Comment: @ErDeepakGarg like so?

Comment: could you please read the question again from scratch, your answer looks promising to me, but you changed the alphabets name of the function, which confuses me what you are trying to do?